# How do i fix this warning?

Tags: warnings

Why do i get this warning?

> Package unnumberedtotoc Warning:
>     adding some features also provided   by KOMA-script classes.
>     Consider switching, as there are much more  features with KOMA.
>   Found at:  https://github.com/johannesbottcher/unnumberedtotoc.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{natbib}                 %
\usepackage{bibentry}                   %
\setlength{\bibsep}{0pt plus 0.3ex}     % No Space
\usepackage{etoolbox}                   %
\makeatletter                           %
\patchcmd{\l@section}{1.5em}{2em}{}{}   %
\makeatother                            %
\usepackage{parskip}                    %
\usepackage{titlepic}                   %
\usepackage[english]{babel}             %
\usepackage{amssymb}                    %
\setlength{\parindent}{0in}             %
\usepackage{mathtools}                  %
\usepackage{booktabs}                   %           
\usepackage{setspace}                   %
\usepackage{graphicx}                   %
\usepackage{epstopdf}                   %
\usepackage{amsmath}                    %
\usepackage{amsfonts}                   %
\usepackage{amsthm}                     %
\usepackage{marginnote}                 %
\usepackage{datetime}                   %
\usepackage{enumitem}                   %
\usepackage{subfigure}                  %
\usepackage{rotating}                   %                   
\usepackage{float}                      %
\usepackage[para,symbol*]{footmisc}     %
\usdate                                 %   
% Save original definition of \marginpar                                                                        %
%\let\oldmarginpar\marginpar                                                                                        %
\usepackage{unnumberedtotoc}
\usepackage{multicol}

% Save original definition of \marginpar                                                                        %
\let\oldmarginpar\marginpar                                                                                     %
                                                                                                                %
% Workaround for todonotes problem with natbib (To Do list title comes out wrong)                               %
\makeatletter\let\chapter\@undefined\makeatother % Undefine \chapter for todonotes                              %


% Command to start a new page, starting on odd-numbered page if twoside option                                  %
% is selected above                                                                                             %
%\newcommand{\clearRHS}{\clearpage\thispagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage\thispagestyle{plain}}                   %


% Number paragraphs and subparagraphs and include them in TOC   
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}    

\usepackage{indentfirst} % Indent first sentence of a new section
\usepackage{endnotes}    % Use endnotes instead of footnotes
%% ============================================================================                                 
\usepackage{D:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/jf/jf}                                                                             
%% ============================================================================                                                                                                         
\usepackage[subfigure]{tocloft}



\usepackage{fancyhdr}\makeatletter \def\@fancyvbox#1#2{\vbox{#2}} \makeatother


\begin{document}





\pagenumbering{gobble}% Remove page numbers (and reset to 1)


\setlist{noitemsep}  % Reduce space between list items (itemize, enumerate, etc.)
\onehalfspacing      % Use 1.5 spacing
% Use endnotes instead of footnotes - redefine \footnote command
\renewcommand{\footnote}{\endnote}  % Endnotes instead of footnotes

\author{blabla\thanks{\rm Gblabla@blabla.se }}



%\thispagestyle{empty}
%\fancyfoot{}
%\fancyhead{}
\title{\LARGE \textbf{American}\footnote{Acknowledgements:.}}  %%MAX LIMIT FOR ACKNOWLEDGEMENTS


\date{}              % No date for final submission



% Create title page with no page number
\maketitle
\thispagestyle{fancy}


\smallskip

\centerline{\bf ABSTRACT}



\clearpage
\thispagestyle{plain}


\tableofcontents




\newpage
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Your document is incomplete

Comment: This is a warning, you can ignore it or use the `silent` option.

Comment: yes just found the solution myself ty anyways

Comment: Everything is in the README file.

Answer (score 4):

You are getting this warning, because the package implements some KOMA-features in a very crude way. If you want to have the features of KOMA-script, consider switching to a KOMA class.

Wait, that is essentially what is already written in the warning. My bad.

---

How to get rid of it?

The Readme of the Github repository states just two options for the package:

> `silent`
>   Suppress the warning that is printed in the log file and the terminal output
>   `indentunnumbered`
>   Indent the unnumbered entries in the table of contents

Use `silent` to suppress the warning.